# Erro ao carregar um video e criar um objeto no django

Tags: python, django

Minha função no Django irá receber um video de meu site, está funcionando normalmente. Então criei a função `create`:

```
   def create(self, request):
       Video.objects.create(file=request.data['file'], creator=self.request.user)
       return Response('ok')
```

Irei definir a função do meu jeito. Mas quando carrego um arquivo do meu disco: `request.data['file'] = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm')` Está me dando o sequinte erro:

```
   def create(self, request):
       request.data['file'] = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm')
       Video.objects.create(file=request.data['file'], creator=self.request.user)
       return Response('ok')
```

OutPut: `*** TypeError: readonly attribute`

Então eu verifiquei o tipo das minhas variaveis.

```
(Pdb) type(request.data['file'])
<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
(Pdb) request.data['file'] = open('/home/developer/Pictures/teste.webm')
(Pdb) type(request.data['file'])
<type 'file'>
```

Ok, eu sei que minhas variaveis possuem tipos diferente, mas como eu torno meu arquivo local no tipo: `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>`

Comment: Já tentou `File(file=open('...'))` onde `from django.core.files.base import File`? Aliás, o erro que deu ali é porque está tentando atribuir um valor em `requests.data`, que é apenas leitura.